Kill mouse event
I am wondering is there a way with Python that
we can detect process that use a click event so we can kill them.
That would help in the step of an anti cheat
I asked my friend if he can code something like this and he gave me this C# code that uses DLL imports:
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(int idHook);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int CallNextHookEx(int idHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

public delegate int HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
private const int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202;
private const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
private const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
private const int WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;

private HookProc mouseHookDelegate;

private int mouseHookID = 0;

private int MouseHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        int eventType = wParam.ToInt32();
        if (eventType == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            leftClicks++;
            clickEvents.Add((DateTime.Now, 0));
            label2.Text = "Left Clicks: " + leftClicks;
        }
        else if (eventType == WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            rightClicks++;
            clickEvents.Add((DateTime.Now, 0));
            label3.Text = "Right Clicks: " + rightClicks;
        }
        else if (eventType == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
        {
            scrollWheelSpins++;
            clickEvents.Add((DateTime.Now, 0));
            label4.Text = "Scroll Wheel Spins: " + scrollWheelSpins;
        }
        else if (eventType == 0x0207) // Middle mouse button down
        {
            middleClicks++;
            clickEvents.Add((DateTime.Now, 0));
            label6.Text = "Middle Clicks: " + middleClicks;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(mouseHookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}



Is this even Python?

So the question is: is it possible to convert this C# code to Python? Is my understanding correct?

Yea just let me know if its possible and how
